# Powers of the Auslander-Reiten translations

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, projective-module

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional algebra over a field $k$, and let $\tau$ be the Auslander-Reiten translation functor vanishing on projective $A$-modules. I'm studing the book "An introduction to Quiver Representations" of Derksen and Weyman and I don't understand the following fact:

**Suppose that A is of inite representation type, and $N$ is a non-projective indecomposable A-module, then there exists a positive $n$ such that $\tau^n(N)=0$.**

Can anyone help me to understand this fact please? I'm also curious about the next 2 questions that naturally arises in trying to understand the above sentence

1. Is the above sentence still true without the assumption that $A$ is of finite representation type?
2. Is it true (always without the assumption that $A$ is of finite representation type) that if $M$ if an $A$-module (not necessarily indecomposable) such that $\tau^m(M)=M$ for $m>0$ then $M=0$.

Thank's for your help.

Comment: The answer to both of your "next 2 questions" is no. If $A$ is symmetric then $\tau M = \Omega^2(M)$. If you take $A = kC_2$ where $k$ has characteristic 2 and $C_2$ is the cyclic group of order 2 then $\Omega^2(k) = k$, so it is a counterexample to both.

Comment: I don't have the book you mention handy, but is it possible that there is a missing assumption? For example, if you assume $A$ to be hereditary, then the statement becomes true.

Answer (score 0):

The statement appears to be false: take the algebra $A = k[x]/(x^2)$.  Then there are precisely two indecomposable $A$-modules, up to isomorphism: $A$ itself, which is projective and injective, and the simple module $S = Ax$, which is neither.  Then $\tau S = S$, so $\tau^n S \neq 0$ for all positive $n$.

Comment: Yes this is precisely the idea that auslander Reiten quivers of quivers with relations can be cyclic. You’re probably right that the text meant the algebra to be hereditary.